# Netlogo - Origin in the corner with code

Tags: netlogo

I need to have a martix of patches which axis are long a power of 2 ( 2^n ) for example 16.

I thought this can be done or having the corner but i need to do this with a line of code because i want it to be set with the setup button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [`resize-world`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#resize-world):

`resize-world 0 (2 ^ n - 1) 0 (2 ^ n - 1)`

You may also want to set the patch size with [`set-patch-size`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#set-patch-size) so that the view remains stays the same size no matter how many patches you have:

`set-patch-size 400 / (2 ^ n)`